# D3 redundant SVG elements after re-initialization

Tags: d3.js

**What I got.**

I got a small D3 forced graph, the data source is a SQL DB. Each node contains two text elements, one do display the node.id `d.id` and another to display the node.name `d.name`. Further I can add and delete nodes through an contextMenu, the relevant SQL queries are working fine and updating the DB as well as the view port. To update the view port I call the`initialize()` function, each time I add or remove an node. The `initialize()` function will be executed, which contains the main D3 logic. Unfortunately I can´t provide a working example as I the code is dependend on to much third party software.

**This is the initialilze() function:**

```
function initialize() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "sql_connection_read.php",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("SQL Verbindung hergestellt.")
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                nodes_sql = data[0]
                links_sql = data[1]
            }
        })

        link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links_sql)
            .join("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("display", "block")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
        
        node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes_sql, d => d.id)
            .join("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        node.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => [d])
            .join("circle")
            .attr("r", 30)
            .style("fill", "whitesmoke")
            .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
            .on("contextmenu", contextMenuNode)

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", 13)
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("pointer-events", "none")
            .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id
            })

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", 13)
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("pointer-events", "none")
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.name
            })

        force
            .nodes(nodes_sql)
            .on("tick", ticked);
            
        force
            .force("link")
            .links(links_sql)
    }
```

This is the addNode function, which points to an PHP file.

```
   function addNode() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "sql_connection_update.php",
            method: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {executionType: "addNode"},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("SQl Query erfolgreich geschrieben.")
                svg.selectAll("circle").selectAll("Text").remove()
                initialize()
            }
        })
    }
```

**What is the problem?**

I realised each time the view port is updated with the `initialize()`function, both text elements `d.id` and `d.name` are not replaced but furthermore another pair will be added. I tried to add `svg.selectAll("circle").selectAll("text").remove();` to avoid such behavior.

[image: How it should be.]

[image: After initialize() function]

**Whats the goal?**

Well to avoid redundant view port elements.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might face a similar issue.

I fixed it by adding `svg.selectAll("text").remove();` only. During the re-initialization.